# Promise object with the use of fetch in javascript

Tags: promise, fetch

Check this example :

```
fetch('/article/promise-chaining/user.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(user => fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${user.name}`))
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(githubUser => new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { // (*)
    let img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = githubUser.avatar_url;
    img.className = "promise-avatar-example";
    document.body.append(img);

    setTimeout(() => {
      img.remove();
      resolve(githubUser); // (**)
    }, 3000);
  }))
  // triggers after 3 seconds
  .then(githubUser => alert(`Finished showing ${githubUser.name}`));
```

It is working. But my question is why image.remove() is not executed first, The image got removed after alert(`Finished showing ${githubUser.name}`).

Here is the example link : https://javascript.info/promise-chaining

Answer (score 1):

img.remove() is an async operation, it will be effectively shown at the next rendering time, so after your alert